# How to send a well formed HTML document to the client?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, domdocument

Hi I want to do the following:

```
$string_foo = "Hello world!";

if (is_not_fully_html( $string_foo )) {

   $show = "<!doctype><html><head></head><body>{$string_foo}</body></html>";

}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $show );

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

But, what happens if `$string_foo` is:

```
$string_foo = "<html>Hello world!</html>";
```

or

```
$string_foo = "<body>Hello world!</body>";
```

or

```
$string_foo = "<head></head><body>Hello world!</body>";
```

or

```
$string_foo = "<head></head>Hello world!";
```

or

```
$string_foo = "<body>Hello world!";
```

**¿how $show = ......................... {$string_foo} ...... will act to return a well formed HTML?**

Comment: Is this a quiz? Why not you try using your php compiler? :o

Comment: Not a quiz! is a question... there's a function or library for this?

Comment: CrisHongKongCRISHK: What @SiGateng meant is, why don't you try your examples out your own?, this will show you what happens. And we expect here on site that you do that before asking so it actually is (more) clear what your concrete programming question is. The answers you got so far are of really low quality as you might have imagined.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called **PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser.** It works great, and it can definitely help you verify the HTML.

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[KvzHTML Library](http://github.com/kvz/kvzlib)

Tutorial

[Generate HTML with PHP](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/10/11/generate-html-with-php/)